# BASH - loop (for) with IF thru each line from file

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I Have file (halted.txt) with data like below

```
IMPORT_FRP_DRAWDOWN_MQ,1
eFXO_IMPORT_RFQ_MQ,1
IMPORT_FROM_MCDM,1
deal_export,1
```

and now the question is how to loop against this file and perform some action (add +1 to the number of the ned) only ones for each line and stop when the number is 5 or >5

```
IFS=$'\n' # make newlines the only separator
set -f    # disable globbing

for p in $(cat < "halted.txt"); do
   if [[ $p == *"5"* ]]; then
       echo "There is 5 on the end", $p
   elif [[ $p > *"5"* ]]; then
       echo "add +1 till 5"
       awk -F, '{$2=$2+1}1' OFS=, halted.txt > temp && mv temp halted.txt
   fi
done
```

Currently, every run's number 1 is increased not only ones but 4 times because I have the 4line inside the file. then the first run will give me

```
IMPORT_FRP_DRAWDOWN_MQ,4
eFXO_IMPORT_RFQ_MQ,4
IMPORT_FROM_MCDM,4
deal_export,4
```

next one 8 etc.
How to make sure that as results only +1 will be added?

Comment: Use IFS to _add_ comma as a separator, then use `read name number` to read the name and number (you can add `-r` if you want: `read -r name number`).  Then do what you need with the name and number.

Comment: Your `awk` command reads the whole file (again — basically ignoring that you just read one line of the original version into `p`) and increments the number by one for all lines.  When it reads the next line, it adds one to every line in the file again.  Repeat for 4 lines, so each line in the file gets 4 added to it.  It's doing what you programmed.  What were you trying to do?  Your input data is boring since all lines contain 1 at the start; is that really what it'll look like?  When will anything be different?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, data inside file will be like this as this is audit file, where information how many times function was started will be stored. Not always all line will have this same number because other parts of code will remove line or add new one. I just need to add only next number to each line at this stage

Comment: I'm really not clear what you're up to.  If you're auditing "functions started", then do you have a list of the functions called in the current "run", as well as the previous list of functions and the number of times each has been called?  If you're just going to add one to each line, there isn't any need to do more than run the `awk` command once.  So, presumably, you have more than that in mind.  If you have a file with the functions called in the order in which they're called, then `sort | uniq -c` (with extra arguments required) can group names together and count the number of lines.

Comment: I have java jmx function, this function will check if service is up (thru jmx) if yes no action will be performed if not script will perform restart, but here is my code, script will try only 5 times to restart. Because I need to store this information I have audit files, and thru audit this + 1 function need to be done. I hope this explains my idea.

Comment: [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rewriting the file with Awk every time you read another line from it. Just do it all in one go with Awk.

```
if awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } ++$NF >= 5 { exit 1 } 1' halted.txt >halted.txt.tmp
then
    mv halted.txt.tmp halted.txt
else
    echo "$0: terminated with error" >&2
    rm halted.txt.tmp # or maybe do this outside the if?
fi
```

Generally you want to avoid looping over lines in Bash, and especially processing the entire file again and again in a loop.

If you want Awk to finish processing but signal a failure, try

```
if awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS=FS; rc=0 } ++$NF >= 5 { rc=1 } 1; END { exit rc }' halted.txt >halted.txt.tmp
then
    : nothing
else
    echo "$0: we are done" >&2
fi
mv halted.txt.tmp halted.txt
```

Comment: Should Awk terminate immediately when it finds a record which reaches 5, or should it keep going but signal at the end that we are done?

Comment: thanks, how to change this to not terminate to other line where is not 5?

Comment: You accept, and then you ask follow-up questions, still without clarifying your question at the top of the page? Oh well, I'll update the answer.